# How to use scipy special functions with scipy newton?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics

Title.

For my homework I am tasked specifically with using scipy.optimize.newton to find the first 4 roots of the airy function scipy.special.airy.

This seems impossible at the moment for one reason.

The newton function takes as input a function, specifically one that has not been evaluated at its argument. This is an issue because the way the airy function is implemented in scipy it seems to fetch and evaluate four different related airy functions at the same time. For example

Ai, Aip, Bi, Bip = airy(xi)

This poses a problem because I want the roots of Ai specifically, but after evaluating this line Ai is a numpy array not a function. Additionally trying to index the airy function inside the argument of the newton such as below doesn't work either.

newton(airy[0],1)

At this point im really confused about how to do it this way specifically. If we were allowed to evaluate the function first and then find roots I can think of a few ways to find the roots from there, but I have no idea how to use newton in this way.

Comment: `lambda xi: airy(xi)[0]` or similar helper function

Comment: @hpaulj Interesting, would you mind explaining why that works? I see that you used a lambda function, but how does this avoid evaluating the function before the newton function is called?

Comment: A `lambda` is equivalent to `def foo(xi): return airy(xi)[0]`, a function definition.  The first argument the `optimize` function is supposed to be function (or more generally any `callable`).  So you can wrap `airy` in some sort of function definition, whether it's a `def` or `lambda`.  Defining a utility function like this is, at least to me, a basic Python coding step.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh okay so fundamentally the newton function is expecting a function (or as you say a callable) whose output upon receiving an array is the airy function in question. The scipy function doesn't work this way though, so you use a wrapper function which does satisfy this?